# Pasar los resultados de una función a un DataFrame

Tags: python

Buenas. Estoy calculando el overlap de los atributos respecto del vector objetivo. Tengo una función que si le ingreso cualquier variable me arroja el %, sin embargo, quiero hacer un data frame en donde me aparezca el atributo y el porcentaje. Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
atributos = []

for atributo in df.drop(columns = ['diagnosis']):
    atributos.append(atributo)
    data = pd.DataFrame(atributos)

for i in atributos:
    var=histogram_overlap(df,i,'diagnosis')
```

El problema que así tengo un ouput que corresponde al último atributo. Me salen todos cuando aplico esta línea de código:

```
for atributo in df.drop(columns = ['diagnosis']):
    print('Atributo:', atributo, 'Porcentaje:', histogram_overlap(df, atributo, 'diagnosis'), '\n')
```

Pero lo anterior no puedo pasarlo a un df. Me pueden orientar por favor?

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Utiliza su método `apply()`

Comment: Aquí te dejo la documentación sobre el método apply al que Christian se refiere: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html. Recomiendo que primero revises la documentación y si la documentación no responde tu pregunta, entonces haz la pregunta aqui.

Comment: ya probé con apply antes de hacer la pregunta

Comment: Toda operación con DataFrames devuelve un DataFrame, no es necesario volver a generar uno

Comment: También sería bueno que pongas algunos datos, así se podrán hacer pruebas

Comment: Por favor coloca una muestra de tus datos y el resultado especrado para poderte orientar.